# Django - Keep the form values filled after form validation

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

When I submit the form and it is not validated for some reason the form is rendered all blank. I am not using the {{ form }} to render the complete form, I like to let other people to customize it.

This is a part of the form:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class = "panel-heading">
            Informações de Contato 
        </div>
        <div class = "panel-body">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                id="id_{{ anuncioForm.nome_contato.name }}" 
                name="{{ anuncioForm.nome_contato.name }}"
                value= "{{ request.user.first_name }} {{request.user.last_name}}"
                placeholder="Nome">
            </div>
            <p class="help-text">{{ anuncioForm.nome_contato.help_text }} </p>
            <br>

            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                id="id_{{ anuncioForm.email_contato.name }}" 
                name="{{ anuncioForm.email_contato.name }}"
                value="{{ request.user.email }} " 
                placeholder="E-mail">
            </div>
            <p class="help-text">{{ anuncioForm.email_contato.help_text }} </p>
            <br>

            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                id="id_{{ anuncioForm.telefone_contato.name }}" 
                name="{{ anuncioForm.telefone_contato.name }}"
                placeholder="Telefone ou Celular">
            </div>
            <p class="help-text">{{ anuncioForm.telefone_contato.help_text }} </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This the view.py

```
def anunciar_imovel(request):
    ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(ImagensAnuncio,
                                        form=ImagensForm, extra=3)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        anuncioForm = AnuncioForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES,
                               queryset=ImagensAnuncio.objects.none())

        if anuncioForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
            novo_anuncio = anuncioForm.save(commit=False)
            novo_anuncio.user = request.user
            novo_anuncio.save()

            for form in formset.cleaned_data:
                imagem = form['imagem']
                photo = ImagensAnuncio(anuncio=novo_anuncio, imagem=imagem)
                photo.save()
            return render(request, 'account/index.html')
    else:
        anuncioForm = AnuncioForm()
        formset = ImageFormSet(queryset=ImagensAnuncio.objects.none())
    return render(request, 'imoveis/anunciar.html', {'anuncioForm':anuncioForm,'formset':formset })
```

What could I do to keep the filled values?

Comment: your code has the bahaviour that you are looking for.

Comment: The values were a test, but I wasn't sure it was the correct approach... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the behavior you want, you have to use the values from `anuncioForm`:

```
<form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class = "panel-heading">
             Informações de Contato 
        </div>
        <div class = "panel-body">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                       id="id_{{ anuncioForm.nome_contato.name }}" 
                       name="{{ anuncioForm.nome_contato.name }}"
                       value= "{{ anuncioForm.nome_contato.value or (request.user.first_name + ; ' + request.user.last_name) }}"
                       placeholder="Nome">
            </div>
            <p class="help-text">{{anuncioForm.nome_contato.help_text }} </p>
            <br>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                       id="id_{{ anuncioForm.email_contato.name }}" 
                       name="{{ anuncioForm.email_contato.name }}"
                       value="{{ anuncioForm.email_contato.value or request.user.email }} " 
                       placeholder="E-mail">
            </div>
            <p class="help-text">{{ anuncioForm.email_contato.help_text }}</p>
            <br>
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-glyphicon glyphicon-phone"></i></span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" 
                       id="id_{{ anuncioForm.telefone_contato.name }}" 
                       name="{{ anuncioForm.telefone_contato.name }}"
                       value="{{ anuncioForm.telefone_contato.value }}"
                       placeholder="Telefone ou Celular">
            </div>
            <p class="help-text">{{ anuncioForm.telefone_contato.help_text }} </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Okay. That is what I though but I wasn't sure if that's the correct approach. Actually now I am doing de the validation with jquery, so the page do not render if the form is not valid (according to my js rules). Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

In your view, if the form is not valid a new blank form is being sent to the template.  You need to send the form that the user filled in so that the errors can be displayed properly.

You also need to adjust your template to show the errors - right now it is not doing that.

To fix the view:

```
def anunciar_imovel(request):
    ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(ImagensAnuncio,
                                        form=ImagensForm, extra=3)
    anuncioForm = AnuncioForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,
                               queryset=ImagensAnuncio.objects.none())

    if anuncioForm.is_valid() and formset.is_valid():
        novo_anuncio = anuncioForm.save(commit=False)
        novo_anuncio.user = request.user
        novo_anuncio.save()

        for form in formset.cleaned_data:
            imagem = form['imagem']
            photo = ImagensAnuncio(anuncio=novo_anuncio, imagem=imagem)
            photo.save()

        return render(request, 'account/index.html')

    return render(request, 'imoveis/anunciar.html',
                  {'anuncioForm':anuncioForm,'formset':formset })
```

To fix the template, you need to check if there are any error on the formset and the individual form itself. I leave this exercise up to you, as [it is detailed in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#rendering-form-error-messages).

Comment: Thank you. Actually I decided to keep it on the html (calling the field values) but your anwser is right! I appreciate your help !